# How to gererate a picture with two letters in Elixir

Tags: image, elixir

I am new to Elixir and would like to know if there is an easy way to gererate a picture with two letters and a custom background (gradient for example).

Would like to do it without ImageMagick. Is it possible in Elixir?

Comment: does it have to be in elixir? Most of the time its easier to generate these in the browser or on the client

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to use Erlang edg [library](http://www1.erlang.org/doc/man/egd.html).
I was using it in one of my test programs to generate GitHub like avatar images. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/Kociamber/identicon/blob/master/lib/identicon.ex).